# How does Rust work with process arguments?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, rust

I'm really confused about Rust processes. I'm trying to call something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/test-video.webm -ab 160k -ac 2 -vn -f mp3 -
```

This should extract sound out of video and send it to stdout. So I've done this:

```
let sound: std::process::Output = Command::new("ffmpeg")
    .arg(format!("-i {}", args.input.to_str().unwrap()))
    .arg("-ab 160k")
    .arg("-ac 2")
    .arg("-vn")
    .arg("-f mp3")
    .arg("-")
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .stdin(Stdio::inherit())
    .stderr(Stdio::inherit())
    .output()
    .unwrap();
```

But for some reason, this doesn't work. It prints this to stderr:

```
Unrecognized option 'i path/to/test-video.webm'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

When I remove the slashes from args (so it looks like `.arg(format!("i {}", ...)).arg("ab 160k")...`, I get this:

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I think I misunderstood how this works, but I tested it on other applications and it seemed to work the way I'm doing it now. What did I miss, how does Rust work with these arguments?

And just to be clear, I know about the ffmpeg crates, but they don't work for me for some reason, I can't even compile them.

Comment: That basic unix rule, `-i` is an argument. You must separate ALL of them. Read the documentation of `Command` all it's written

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```rust
    let sound: std::process::Output = Command::new("ffmpeg")
        .arg("-i")
        .arg(args.input.to_str().unwrap())
        .arg("-ab")
        .arg("160k")
        .arg("-ac")
        .arg("2")
        .arg("-vn")
        .arg("-f")
        .arg("mp3")
        .arg("-")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stdin(Stdio::inherit())
        .stderr(Stdio::inherit())
        .output()
        .unwrap();
```

Comment: Although not the case for `ffmpeg`, some binaries do support bundling the value with the option by using `-i=...`, or even just `-i...`, so you could use that instead. Also, if one prefers, they can use `.args(["-ab", "160k"])` instead of `.arg("-ab").arg("160k")` to reinforce that one is the value of the other to the reader.